# Referenceing dll's in an user directory fails in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, telerik

I have a c# solution with some projects. For the solution I have created a folder for extenal libs. I have copied some Telerik-dll's from the instalation to the libs folder.

Now my problem:
When I add the dll's to the projectes (I choose the copied dll's from the libs folder) Visual Studio takes always the dll's of the installation source and not the dll's of my libs folder.

How can I fix this? I'm afraid that my colleagues could not compile the solution because the dll's are referenced to a missing directory (would happen if they don't have installed the correct Telerik version).

Thanks

**Edit:** 
For example:
I reference with the file chooser
"C:\vendors\Libs\Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.dll"
Visual Studio references
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\RadControls for Silverlight Q2 2011\Binaries\Silverlight\Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.dll"

Answer (score 0):

Properties of the references - set *Embed Interop Type* to **false** and set *Copy Local* to **true**

Comment: I am not sure if that is the answer of my question. I have added an example.